# dropbox extension minimizes with Unable to setup extension context - error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4099.)

Tags: ios, dropbox, uidocumentpickervc

I have implemented `documentPicker` to import files in my app. I can open other app extension and import file.

Issue is when I go to background. Suppose Dropbox extension is downloading a file to be imported and I press `Home` button. Again when I open app extension is dismissed and downloading is cancelled. On console `Unable to setup extension context - error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 4099.)` is printed. 
But for other apps like Box, OneDrive, iCloudDrive, extesion is not dismissed.

I opened Drive app and tried to import file from Dropbox and while downloading was in progress pressed `Home` button. Then opened Drive. But in drive, downloading continued.